# The annotation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have some kind of strange problem with symfony and doctrine. While sending project to development server getting an error:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>     [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\joinTable" in property Acme\CampaignInterfaceBundle\Entity\Campaign::$users does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

CODE part here:

> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @var Acme\UsersBundle\Entity\User
>  * 
>  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UsersBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="campaigns")
>  * @ORM\joinTable(name="acme.campaign_users",
>  *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="campaign_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
>  *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
>  *      )
>  */
> private $users;
> ```

Some namespace problem?

Answer (score 4):

Problem was in

```
@ORM\joinTable(name="jcdecaux.campaign_users", ...
```

`joinTable` should be capitalized as in

```
@ORM\JoinTable, ...
```

Comment: For what it's worth I had this problem too, but this was because a "use" statement incorrectly had a '\' before it. "use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;" should have been "use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;".